# Find a representation of $\neg p$, $p \wedge q$, $p \vee q$, $p \rightarrow q$, and $p \leftrightarrow q$ using only the logical connective nand.

Tags: logic

> a) Find a representation of each of the following statements using only the logical connective nand.
>   i. $\neg p$
>   ii. $p \wedge q$
>   iii. $p \vee q$
>   iv. $p \rightarrow q$
>   v. $p \leftrightarrow q$
>
> b) Explain why every statement has a representation using only the logical connective nand.

My work so far:

i. $\neg p \Leftrightarrow p \barwedge p$
iii. $p \vee q \Leftrightarrow (p \barwedge p) \barwedge (q \barwedge q)$

Comment: Yes.  So far, so good.  What problem do you have with the otters?

Comment: My problem is I can't figure out what they are

Comment: Why not?  You managed those two just fine.  What have you tried with the others?

Comment: I don't know where to start with the others, that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\nand{\barwedge}$

> i. $\neg p$

Since $p=p\wedge p$ , then indeed $\neg p = p\nand p$ $\checkmark$

> ii. $p \wedge q$

Well, $p\wedge q = \neg(p\nand q)$ so...

> iii. $p \vee q$

Yes, $p\vee q = \neg(\neg p\wedge \neg q) = \neg p\nand \neg q=(p\nand p)\nand(q\nand q)$ $\checkmark$

> iv. $p \rightarrow q$

Well $p\to q = \neg p\vee q$ so...

> v. $p \leftrightarrow q$

Likewise $p\leftrightarrow q = (p\to q)\wedge (q\to p)$ so...

Comment: We are only allowed to use $\barwedge$, no other operators can be used. I know how to solve all five of them if I am allowed to use $\neg$, but I can't.

Comment: But you know that $\neg f(p,q)=f(p,q)\nand f(p,q)$... It's the first one you did, and you used that very fact to express $p\vee q$ as $(p\nand p)\nand (q\nand q)$

Comment: @Shea But You've already showed haw to replace negation with nand.

Comment: Isn't that the same as saying $p \barwedge q \Leftrightarrow \neg (p \wedge q)$? If so, then how does that help me?

Comment: @JaroslawMatlak I know how to replace negation of a single statement with nand, but not a conjunctive statement.

Comment: ...just substitute...  $\neg x=x\nand x$ when $x$ is $(p\land q)$

Comment: @Shea and if we take another statement $a\equiv p\wedge q$, then how do you write $\neg a$ using only nand?

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I didn't think of this...